# logback configuration is not seen in applet

Tags: java, applet, log4j, slf4j, logback

I use `logback` (via `slf4j`) in a Java applet with configuration stored in `logback.xml` file in the applet root directory. Running in Eclipse it can find and load config placed somewhere in classpath. But it doesn't load configuration from applet jar. 
I suspect this issue is not related with `logback` but with applet itself. I have no experience with applets at all.

[EDIT]

`logback.xml` (logging configuration file) is in the root directory of the jar, the rest of jar content seems is not relevant. It's the typical location of logging configuration file in jar files so the issue is not related with the file location. I checked the jar file. Actually I have 2 jar files: server side and applet (client side). Logging configuration works fine on server side, so I suspect it's something related with applet specifics.

[EDIT2]

I don't load logging configuration explicitly, it's done by `logback` library, it looks for specific file name in classpath.

[EDIT3]

Applet setup:

```
<applet name="name" id="game" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Please visit our site"
    archive="my.jar" code="path/to/main.class" mayscript="" title="Java">
    <param name="boxborder" value="false">
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
    <param name="image" value="http://www.oursite.com/img/splash.gif">
    <param name="centerimage" value="true">
    <param name="boxbgcolor" value="black">
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx384m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:CompileThreshold=1500 -Xincgc -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xss6m">
    <div class="nojava">
        <h1>
            Please Update Java</h1>
        <p>
            It appears that you do not have Java installed, or your version of Java is out of
            date. To play this game for free please <a target="_blank" href="http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp">
                click here</a> to download the latest version of Java. </p>
    </div>
</applet>
```

[EDIT4]

Printed logback's internal diagnostic info, it says it cannot find `logback.xml`

Comment: Could it be a problem with regards to permissions somehow? Do you get any output on Java console at all? Is the applet signed?

Comment: yes, I receive log messages from logback, but my custom configuration is not applied (e.g. I specify to output only INFO and up messages, but receive also DEBUG - because of default configuration). Applet is signed (does this matter?) I know nothing about applet permissions, sorry.

Comment: could you write the code bit where you try to load the configuration from the jar?

Comment: @posdef: I don't :) it's done automatically by `logback`, the same as by `log4j` I believe

Comment: How do you package your Jar in that case? It sounds to me that it does not get added in the JAR somehow. Unfortunately I'm not very knowledgeable in neither of them :S

Comment: hmm, i see... Can't really say why in that case. As a last resort you might try to debug the applet remotely, by "hooking up" eclipse debugger to the applet. Since it's not your own code that loads the config file, I doubt it'd be of much help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved

The problem wasn't related with logback or applet. I was putting configuration file into the jar after it was already signed. Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're not packaging the log configuration file in the jar?
Make sure its in the jar. Also, you should better use `System.out.println(...)` until you figure it out, as you will otherwise see no output.

Comment: It's in the root directory of the jar. I'm receiving output from logback to the applet console, the problem is my custom configuration is not applied, probably because it cannot be found or accessed

Comment: Perhaps you could show us some code and the structure of your jar, illustrating where your log config file is...?

Comment: Do you have the logback libraries on the classpath for the applet in the html page?
Could you please post the relevant bit of HTML code for the applet's setup?

Comment: they are included into my jar and work fine because I receive logs in Java console, but custom configuration doesn't work. Please check updated question for applet setup.

Comment: I suspect you might be having more than one logback.xml on your classpath. If you're running Linux, I can send you a script to check which jars contain a file you're expecting to have on your classpath. If there is another logback.xml which is getting loaded before yours, well... that could be your problem.

Comment: `Logback` looks for `logback.groovy`, `logback-test.xml` or `logback.xml` file. The applet uses single jar file as its source, and this jar contains single `logback.xml` in its root directory.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that Logback doesn't load the configuration? Maybe you just don't see anything because there is no appender or other output facility.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html#logging) I assume that you have to use Java Logging API. So instead of using logback I would switch to [slf4j-jdk14.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

If you see that logback loads the configuration: did you use

```
<configuration debug="true" >
```

to see more information?

Comment: I've printed logback's diagnostic info, it says it cannot find `logback.xml`